# How to apply a callback to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, callback

I have this following callbacks. But if I start my player is going to show me always the second callback. How can I make a callback and show both videos random?

```
callback('{"video": {"mp4": "http://c0026122.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/193807.mp4", "webm": "http://5860e9e4db2f4cebe1e6-cc12bb9b5e092d34d0fadb7ce5f280a3.r47.cf1.rackcdn.com/193807.webm", "title": "Touch"}}');
callback('{"video": {"mp4": "http://c0026125.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/064915.mp4", "webm": "http://a95a046574a64b9ea43b-53264ce826f5cfe73ee69a0c3c37eccc.r68.cf1.rackcdn.com/64915.webm", "title": "Grace / Fever / Dinner / Heart to Heart / Videogame"}}');
return;
```

Comment: Well, what does `callback` currently do? What's the context of this code? How is it executed?

Comment: Do you want to show both videos? thats what i understand from your question. Please be more specific with your question because it is very unclear what you want. Also it would be helpful to know what the callback currenly does. Like @FelixKling said

Comment: Ok being more clear, that callback is extracting that video and put it in src="" in my html. What it does now? Is showing only my second callback. If I comment second callback is showing the first video. But what I want is to show all videos. When I refresh the page to choose one of the videos from those callbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking what I think you're asking and you would like to show a random video, then you may want to consider generating a random number from an array of videos.

```
var videos = [ // Place any and all videos in this array
    {"video": {"mp4": "http://c0026122.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/193807.mp4", "webm": "http://5860e9e4db2f4cebe1e6-cc12bb9b5e092d34d0fadb7ce5f280a3.r47.cf1.rackcdn.com/193807.webm", "title": "Touch"}},
    {"video": {"mp4": "http://c0026125.cdn1.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/064915.mp4", "webm": "http://a95a046574a64b9ea43b-53264ce826f5cfe73ee69a0c3c37eccc.r68.cf1.rackcdn.com/64915.webm", "title": "Grace / Fever / Dinner / Heart to Heart / Videogame"}}
];

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length); // Generate random number based on number of videos

callback(videos[rand]); // Run the callback with a random video
```

Comment: But what if I have more than 2 videos there? Do I have to create a callback for each?

Comment: You would generate more random numbers based on the video, and at that point it would be better to put them in an array. I'll update the answer.